# Can't to send email from php

Tags: php, email, mercury-mta

I have problem with send mail from php:
I have config mercury and sent success mail at display program mercury, but in php, mail sent but not received.
this is my php code:

```
$to = "my_email@gmail.com";
$subject = "Test email from localhost with Mercury";
$fromheader = "From : admin@df.vn";
$content = "This email is a test mail send from localhost. If you read this line, it's working OK ";
$ok = mail($to,$subject,$content,$fromheader);
if($ok) 
echo "Mail send OK. Look at MM proccess to watch if it out the localhost. If error, check all your step again !";
else echo "Holly sh!t, something wrong ?";
```

Comment: Please Show your Code.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: Sorry,i have update code. @HamzaZafeer

Comment: I'm using windows 10, @keziah